# Storing Country, State, City and Zip in NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, lithium, nosql

Hey I am trying to come up with a good schema for storing country, state, city, zip in a NoSQL(MongoDB) and I wanted from feed back on this schema.

```
{
    _id: xxxxx,
    country: {
        name: "United States",
        currency: "USD",
        states: {
                { 
                name: "NY"
                cites {
                      "name": Bronx
                     }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I was going for was storing a country as a top level. Then countries have states as an array and states has cities as an array and cities will have an array of zip codes. THoughts please?

Comment: Depends on how you need to query the data. What kinds of queries will you be using?

Comment: At times I will just one to query states. At other times I will just want to query zipcodes in a city.

Comment: I will want access to at the data and want it to relate somehow. Just not sure of the best way(this would be so much easier with RDBMS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your schema is okay in mongo [you can index array fields for perf](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) and [query subdocuments and partial arrays with $slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields).

Comment: @Devin: I'm just curious what way you went with and why. How did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cities shouldn't have arrays of zip-codes as those can span across cities.  I would instead have zip codes have of states and then cities.  See the last area of this page for details:  http://www.carrierroutes.com/ZIPCodes.html

Comment: You approach sounds backwards and hard to enter. Whats the advantage of that way?